# Difference between login name and user name

Tags: linux

I searched the man for passwd in order to understand the file structure :

```
man 5 passwd
```

The man presented that each row contain optional 7 fields, two of them are "login name"  and the other "user name or comment field".

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross site duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307452/what-is-the-difference-between-user-name-display-name-and-log-in-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login name is the value you would enter at the `login:` prompt before entering your password. The user name is the text description for that account, which would ideally be the full name of the person who owns the account or the usage of the account.

`charlie:x:1003:1003:Charlie Haddock:/home/charlie:/bin/bash`

In the above example, `charlie` is the login name.